# Update a value of a column depending on another column's value. Inside a trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

In this table,the variable "duration" can only be either 'A' or 'S' (i already established that with a CHECK CONSTRAINT, when I created the table). If the value of "duration" is 'A' then the column "semester" (NUMBER) should always be NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_duration1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF DURATION
ON SUBJECT
BEGIN
   CASE WHEN INSERTING THEN
        UPDATE SUBJECT
        SET SEMESTER = NULL
        WHERE DURATION = 'A';
   CASE WHEN UPDATING THEN
        UPDATE SUBJECT
        SET SEMESTER = NULL
        WHERE DURATION = 'A';
   END CASE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that this should be a row-level trigger.

Test table:

```
SQL> create table subject (id number, duration varchar2(1), semester number);

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trigger_duration1
  2    before insert or update of duration
  3    on subject
  4    for each row
  5  begin
  6    :new.semester := case when :new.duration = 'A' then null
  7                          else :new.semester
  8                     end;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into subject (id, duration, semester) values (1, 'S', 3);

1 row created.

SQL> update subject set duration = 'A' where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from subject;

        ID D   SEMESTER
---------- - ----------
         1 A

SQL>
```